# Can I get the scores calculated by whoosh for each document while searching?

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, whoosh

I am trying to implement Okapi BM25 to search documents by query using python [**whoosh**](http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.

My understanding is that whoosh calculates the scores for each documents using BM25 according to the query and then sorts it to give the best result.

I use

```
results = searcher.search(query)
```

to get the document best matched to the query.

How can I get the scores for each document?
Is there any other way to get scores for BM25 ranking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the computed score by using the `score` attribute:

```
for r in results:
    print r, r.score
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the different scoring alog or retrieval.

For an example Tf-IDF, Frequency, BM25.

If you want score then here is the method.

```
results = searcher.search(query)

for hit in results:
  print("the Score", hit.score)
  print("the rank", hit.rank)
  print("the document number", hit.docnum)
```